# How do I rename multiple folder/subfolder contents with automator without affecting the folders themselves?

Tags: rename, file-rename, automator, finder, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files with automator so they are sequential. All the files are already in the correct order.

I tried:

1. Get Selected Finder Items
2. Get Folder Contents (checked repeat for each subfolder found)
3. Rename Finder Items: Make Sequential

I'm giving each item a new name so it appears with 3 digits (001.xxx) and continues from there.

I'm only wanting to rename the folder contents. For example. I have a folder with 10 subfolders. In each subfolder are 20 images with names like image001, image002, etc. I want to rename the images as 001, 002, 003. But I want this to start over for each subfolder.

When I run the automator script above, It will rename the first subfolder 001, then it will name the first image (image001) inside the first subfolder 002. The last image (image020) will be 021, then the 2nd subfolder would be renamed 022, the first image of it (image001) will be renamed 023, and so on.

How can I get it to leave the names of the subfolders alone and just rename the contents (image001 = 001, etc) but once it finishes with the 20 images in the first subfolder, it goes to the 2nd subfolder and names those images 001 to 020 as well?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is too much for Automator; it is not able to perform repeats of this nature.  However, it is a simple job for AppleScript:

```
set f to choose folder -- Select Master Folder

tell application "Finder"
    set subF to every folder of folder f
    repeat with eachFolder in subF
        set counter to 1
        set allFiles to (every file of eachFolder)
        repeat with oneFile in allFiles
            set newFileName to my pad(counter, 3)
            set correctExtension to oneFile's name extension
            set oneFile's name to (newFileName & "." & correctExtension)
            set counter to counter + 1
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell

on pad(num, howLong)
    set thisNum to num as text
    set c to count thisNum
    repeat howLong - c times
        set thisNum to "0" & thisNum
    end repeat
    return thisNum as text
end pad
```

This should work; it is a modification of a script that I have used in the past.  However, before running it on your real files, make a copy somewhere first to try it out, and reply here if there are any problems.